# generate tables from entities - synchronized

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, annotations, wizard

In netbeans there is a great wizard function to create entities from a database ([Entity_Classes_From_Database](http://wiki.netbeans.org/TS_65_Entity_Classes_From_Database)). The wizard also creates NamedQueries like

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c");
...
```

automagically.

Is there also a function for doing it the other way around, i.e. make NetBeans create a database from my entity classes (also using @ManyToOne annotations and other complex schemata)? And will changes in the entities be reflected to the database?

Or do I have to study how to create good databases first? How is your way of creating an enterprise application? I am using NetBeans instead of Eclipse because of the huge amount of wizards (especially when it comes to REST-based web services)

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed as named queries are obsolete when creating the RestService from the entities as a Facade is created with exactly the same functionality.